# Subtract all contours from image except the one with the largest area

Tags: c++, opencv, contour, subtraction, area

```
cv::Mat thr;

std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > contours;
std::vector<std::vector<cv::Vec4i> > hierarchy;

int largest_area          = 0;
int largest_contour_index = 0;

cv::findContours( thr, contours, hierarchy,CV_RETR_CCOMP, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE ); // Find the contours in the image

for( int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++ )                                           // iterate through each contour.
{
   double a = contourArea( contours[i], false );                                        // Find the area of contour
   if(a > largest_area)
   {
      largest_area          = a;
      largest_contour_index = i;                                                    // Store the index of largest contour
   }

}
```

What should I do after finding the index of the largest contour? How I can delete all the other contours with its inner areas? 
Image is binary (cv::Mat thr). Just black background with white areas.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, deleting contours with its inner areas is equal to fill them to black. This can be done by drawing the contour regions with black color:

```
for (size_t i=0; i<contours.size(); ++i) {
    if (i != largest_contour_index) { // not the largest one
        cv::drawContours(thr, contours, i, cv::Scalar(0,0,0), CV_FILLED);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

After finding contours find index of biggest contour and draw that contour on Mat.

```
int indexOfBiggestContour = -1;
int sizeOfBiggestContour = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
{
    if (contours[i].size() > sizeOfBiggestContour)
    {
        sizeOfBiggestContour = contours[i].size();
        indexOfBiggestContour = i;
    }
}
cv::Mat newImage;
drawContours(newImage, contours, indexOfBiggestContour, Scalar(255), CV_FILLED, 8, hierarchy);
```